# Upload a file in browser using Selenium C# without NoFileChosen option

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, autoit-c#-wrapper

I am trying to upload a file. My application only has a Browse button and no place to send any file path. So I am unable to use `SendKeys.SendWait(@"filepath");` I tried using `JavaScriptExecutor` but getting error while using the below code:

```
IWebElement upload = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[starts-with(@class,'addDoc') and contains(text(),'Browse')]"));

string filepath = @"C:/Users/../Amazon vs Walmart.pdf";
String script = "document.upload.value= " + filepath;
((IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver).ExecuteScript(script);
```

> Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Why am I getting the exception?

Comment: Its probably complaining because a PDF file doesnt contain javascript in a readable format

Comment: Welcome Kanika. Always make sure to have your question clear to your users. Is your problem the reason for the exception?

Comment: @BugFinder: I tried with xlsx, still I am getting javascript exception - OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'javascript error: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)

Comment: ok but an excel spreadsheet isnt a javascript either..  it might be the file you want to execute the script on, but you seem to be trying to run non javascript as javascript this makes no sense

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Though I tried using AutoItX to upload file and it worked. Below is the code for the same - 
to  get AutoItX, I installed Nugget package - AutoItX.DotNet

```
AutoItX.ControlFocus("Open", "", "Edit1");
AutoItX.ControlSetText("Open", "", "Edit1", filepath);
AutoItX.ControlClick("Open", "", "Button1");
```

But still, I would like to explore using JS as well.

Answer (score 0):

Interacting with file browsing windows is outside the scope of what the webdriver can do. When you click browse the browser passes you off to the OS to find the file. Javascript cannot act on these windows.

SendWait is used as a trick to pass the uri of the file to the open the window and return. If that is not working you will need to use something to interact with OS windows.

I personally use [InputSimulatorCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/InputSimulatorCore/) to handle issues like this when working with IE, which has lots of these type of issues with file downloads.

**Edit:** If you control the application changing to a forms based upload will allow you to do the testing in Selenium and is the best option. If not you can also directly do a post to the upload endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with the code you posted. First, you’re attempting to call `ExecuteScript` with invalid JavaScript. To wit, once your strings are concatenated, your JavaScript looks like this:

```
document.upload.value= C:/Users/../Amazon vs Walmart.pdf
```

Note that there are no quotes around the string you’re actually attempting to set. The syntactically correct JavaScript would be:

```
// Note carefully the quotes around the string literal. 
document.upload.value='C:/Users/../Amazon vs Walmart.pdf'
```

To yield that, your concatenation code would need to look like this:

```
string script = "document.upload.value='" + filepath + "'";
```

The second issue is that you’re attempting to invoke uploading a file. Assuming the upload is accomplished by using standard HTML mechanisms, that means that somewhere on the page, there is am `<input type="file">` element. It might be hidden, but it’s there somewhere on the page. To upload a file, you can use the `SendKeys` method on that element. The file upload case is one of the very few exceptions for `SendKeys` to the rule that elements to be interacted with must be visible to the user (at least with the most recent versions of browsers and browser drivers. If the application is using some non-standard upload mechanism, like a pure JavaScript implementation, or some sort of Flash component, then you’ll need to use some other method to communicate with that component.

Comment: Thank you Jim.
I got you, I have corrected the document.upload.Value to fall under quotes - But I am still getting the below javascript exception - 

OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'javascript error: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)'

Comment: If `upload` is the name of the `<input type="file">` element on the document that performs the upload, then no, JavaScript won’t be an option. Modern versions of browsers do not allow JavaScript to set the `value` property of file upload elements as a security measure. Using `IWebElement.SendKeys` is a tested cross-browser mechanism documented by the W3C WebDriver Specification, and will work across platforms. In my opinion, this makes it superior to both single-platform solutions and those based on proprietary, closed-source software.